# Listen to mouse events in a custom directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, directive

I have a custom directive called side-menu, which I can use at my index.html as follows.

```
<side-menu></side-menu>
```

Inside the directive, there is a controller. This controller is in a separate file (SidebarController.js). Following is the template file of my directive:

```
<div class="sidebarContainer" ng-controller="SidebarController as sidebar">
...
</div>
```

This controller listens to mouse events in the directive. For example, following is a line from the controller:

```
angular.element('#sidebarContainer ul li').on('mouseleave', 'li.item > i', function ($event){...})
```

which listens to mouseleave event on a list item inside the directive. However, I have to carry this controller outside the directive, because it won't let me create an isolated scope on the directive. I changed the layout of my index.html as follows:

```
<div class="sidebarContainer">
    <side-menu></side-menu>
</div>
```

The problem is, the controller no longer listens to anything inside the directive. All the DOM elements are still at same locations. But the controller only listens to them when I put it inside the directive. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all `AngularJs` will not be happy if you use DOM operations     inside controllers. For that very reason we use `directives`. So I suggest you use all DOM operation inside directives.
2. Also you can use event handlers provided by angular (eg. `ng-mouseleave`  in your case) instead of jquery way.
3. Also isolated scope could not catch methods and variables defined inside parent controller. For that purpose you can use `$parent` property.

eg.
`<li class="item" ng-mouseleave="$parent.mouseLeft('Item 1')"><i>Item 1</i></li>`

#### You can go through this plunker code, which i have created for you.

https://plnkr.co/FWhus72HV7v7vTWfmBLQ

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will try your suggestions in short time.